# Powershell Associative Array

Tags: powershell

I think what I am after is an associative array here but I'm not too sure.

Quite simple what I want to do is this

```
 ServiceArray
 ben     gold
 harry   red
 joe     green
 tim     yellow
```

I want to have that in an array that I can call so $servicearray.ben would return gold.

Anyone have any pointers?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You want a HashTable:

```
$ServiceArray = @{
   Ben = 'gold';
   Harry = 'red';
   Joe = 'green';
   Time = 'yellow';
 }
$ServiceArray.Ben

# Result:
# gold
```

If you want more "columns", you can create a `HashTable` of `PSCustomObject`. You can build `PSCustomObject` objects using a `HashTable`, as @mjolinor mentioned.

```
$ObjectList = @{
    Ben = 
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Color = 'Gold';
        Shape = 'Square';
    };
    Harry =
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Color = 'Red';
        Shape = 'Round';
    };
    Joe =
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Color = 'Green';
        Shape = 'Triangle';
    };
    Tim =
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Color = 'Yellow';
        Shape = 'Rectangle';
    };
};

# Syntax: Use dot-notation to access "Ben"
$ObjectList.Ben.Color; # Gold
$ObjectList.Ben.Shape; # Square

# Different syntax: Use the string indexer to access "Ben"
$ObjectList['Ben'].Color; # Gold
$ObjectList['Tim'].Shape; # Rectangle
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you. What if you want to expand it to more columns? Say ben gold man or harry red woman

Comment: If you want more columns, it's time to create a custom object.

Comment: Updated answer to accommodate "more columns." :)